# IIS AppPool not starting because Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) is not getting started

Tags: iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012, application-pool, was

**My AppPools are not starting in IIS**. I initially had an error with the "appPools" path (it had got accidentally deleted). I recreated the folder.

Since that did not solve the issue, i tried restarting WAS and reset IIS. But, once WAS is stopped, even WAS is not getting restarted.

I tried

- Troubleshooting the issue with **Process Monitor**. But, i don't see any error now regarding file access permission issues
- Replacing the `applicationHost.config` file from the `c:/inetpub/history` folder

OS : **Windows Server 2012**

IIS : **IIS 8.0**

I am getting the following errors when I try to start the **Windows Process Activation Service** through **services.msc**.

Please find below the **error messages in the EventLog**.
Kindly give any suggestions on how I can start the app pool again.

```
Source : WAS
Event ID : 5036
Error : The configuration manager for Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) did not initialize. The data field contains the error number.

Source : Service Control Manager
Event ID : 7023
Error : The Windows Process Activation Service service terminated with the following error: The system cannot find the path specified.

Source : Service Control Manager
Event ID : 7001
Error : The World Wide Web Publishing Service service depends on the Windows Process Activation Service service which failed to start because of the following error: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: Ensure that applicationHost.config has valid xml. Also, which folder you recreated which was accidentally deleted?

Comment: I moved the "c:\intepub\temp\appPools" to another location to see if it gets recreated. But it did not, so I moved it back. applicationHost.config file seems to have valid XML (I tried opening it in IE) and it did not show any error. Isn't that what you meant?

Comment: Try running command prompt as an administrator and then run "net start was" to see if you encounter the same error(s)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did run the command. I got the same error "System error 3 has occurred.The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Can you remove the IIS feature using server manager and install it again?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Eventually this issue was due to an extra space in the end of the file path in the WAS registry entry 'ConfigIsolationPath'. it was '%systemdrive%\inetpub\temp\appPools ' instead of '%systemdrive%\inetpub\temp\appPools'. Had modified it before when the entry was pointing wrongly to another drive.

Comment: Great that you managed to figure it out :)

Comment: @BlackCursor Where is this registry entry

Answer (score 4):

I had faced this issue after I had tried an `iisreset` which somehow had failed and had thrown this error(although I had started cmd as an administrator):

[image]

This issue went away when I did another `iisreset` and this time it was successful

Comment: This was the solution (Windows 11) - after iisreset the server was not started